# Which is correct, Credential or Credentials?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is singular correct, or is plural of "credential" correct for a single username & password pair?

Comment: 1. The username-password pair is **not** "credentials." 2. *Credential* is not relevant in the sense of "proof of identity or achievement," -- in this sense, the plural is used. An individual document may be called a "credential," but it is rather odd to do so.

Comment: The question would rather be "What is an expression for the username-password pair of a user?" That may be asked on stackoverflow.com or other appropriate tech site.

Comment: @Kris, a username-password pair is as much a credential (more commonly, *credentials*) as the letter Samuel Johnson asked for when requesting "A short letter for me to show… as a kind of Credential".

Comment: @JonHanna Source, please?

Comment: @Kris What's your basis for asserting that a username-password pair isn't referred to as "credentials"? As far as I'm concerned, it's a completely standard term in the industry - that's based on 10+ years of experience, and verified by quickly Googling "username password credentials" just now.

Comment: @Kris source for what? If you hold that there is some sort of magical distinction between some text passed between computers and some text written on paper, I would say that the burden of proof; or at least the burden of making some sort of supporting argument, is with you.

Comment: Morton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credential Please see the subtle differences. My comment is based on experience since 1976 (Mainframes to Win PCs). HTH.

Comment: @Kris I'm sorry, I really don't understand the point you're making at all. The Wikipedia article says "The classic combination of a user's account number or name and a secret password is a widely used example of IT credentials".

Comment: I don't think personal experience is relevant, but the collective experience is. I've discovered that different tech resources will use singular and plural interchangeably. MSDN will call something "NetworkCredential", but Amazon Web Services uses the plural. Personal experiences with a particular technology-set may lend to a bias. That's why I think Morton's answer is most correct.

Comment: @Morton Much earlier than that, it says "Examples of credentials .include ... passwords, user names, ..." -- please see the difference.

Comment: @Kris I still don't understand, which might well be my own stupidity; but I don't think you're really trying to help me understand, so let's just leave it here.

Comment: @Samuel Thanks, I stand corrected on the "always...never" part of my answer.  It's a very good point you make about the difference between personal and collective experience.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This isn't a question you can answer by thinking about the grammar - it's just a case of conventional usage.

I've previously worked in the tech industry, and we would always say **credentials**, never **credential**.  That would still be true even if the credentials were a single item like a certificate.  *[Edit to add: but Samuel has provided a counter-example to this in a comment on the OP.]*

In wider English, **credential** is valid - it's used for example in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credential) - but it's still more common to use the plural (see [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/credential) for confirmation).  For example, I could say that I have **presented my credentials** to someone if I have shown them my passport, even though I've only shown them one physical item.

Comment: I think you have missed the basic point here. Please see my comment at OP.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credential

Comment: @Kris How about you make your own answer instead of commentting on every answer the same un-insightful, un-helpful comment? As Morton pointed out in comments on the question: "The classic combination of a user's account number or name and a secret password is a widely used example of IT credentials" Hence, pair can be referred to as credentials.

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure that a Wiki page which states "In many democratic nations, press credential [sic] are [sic] not required" is a good grammar reference here ;) Certainly in British English the plural is much more commonly used even when referring to a single object (e.g. a security pass), as the dictionary references in other posts state.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct, and both have been used in both plural and singular form whether literally (when one has an actual proof of one's being authorised to do something) and figuratively in both plural and singular of a single piece of such evidence from the 1600s until the current day.

The plural use is far more common, as the OED confirms.

As such it's a matter of style, but if you don't have a rule from a style guide, you are probably better off using *credentials*, but also better off not criticising someone who uses *credential* for doing so.

Comment: I think you have missed the basic point here. Please see my comment at OP.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of providing proof of who you are with a user name and password, "Credentials" should be used, even if there is only one set of username & password.

When you log into a website, for example, you have to prove who you are.  You do this with at least two pieces of information:

1. Your User name, which is used to determine if you have an account
2. Your password, which is used to determine if you can access the account

In some cases, you will have to provide one credential at a time.  I've heard that Google and others are starting to do this, where you provide a user name first, then click into another page that will then ask for the password for that account.  In these cases, each page would ask for one credential.

Other places may ask you for even more credentials, such as verifying a secret picture and phrase, answering security questions, etc.

By the way, you mentioned in a comment on your question that MSDN refers to it as a 'networkcredential.'  I believe the class is called `NetworkCredential` so that programmers know there is only one set of credentials in there, as naming the class `NetworkCredentials` would make it seem as though the class is a collection of `NetworkCredential` objects.  This is common practice in programming.

If you read the description for the `NetworkCredential` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx, you'll see the description uses `Credentials`:

> Provides credentials for password-based authentication schemes such as
>   basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Oxford Dictionaries Online confirms that ***credential*** does exist in the singular (*achievement, quality or aspect of a person's background, especially when used to indicate their suitability for something*) but it notes that it is usually used in the plural - which is my own experience.

And as Morton notes in his answer it would be usual to say that one had presented one's *credentials* even if it only involved one item.

Comment: The question, sadly,  is *not* whether 'credential' exists, but whether it is the correct term for a username+password.

Comment: @Kris If you look in the OED (assuming that meets your criteria for 'a good dictionary') you will get an exhaustive treatment of he subject, including the contexts in which *credential* is used in the singular, and when in the plural. I was giving a more shorthand version which I judged was needed in the circumstances.