# What is the plural of credentials?

Tags: single-word-requests

Following from this question: [Which is correct, Credential or Credentials?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252073/which-is-correct-credential-or-credentials)

the PO was asking if he can use `credential` in the singular form, answers indicated that the common way to address it is credentials (even though it's for one person)

How can I address the credentials in the sense of multiple users' credentials?

Comment: It is still credentials. You can add the possessive form of the group you are addressing (like you had used "multiple users' credentials") to denote whose credentials they are, but at the end of the day the pile of credentials are just credentials. Much like a bowl of potato chips still contains potato chips even if multiple people own each different chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Credentials."

Regardless of how many credentials each user has, it would still be correct to refer to "a group of users' credentials"